# htaccess redirect to lang page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How can I redirect 
from

```
http://host_name.com/booking?param=1&param=2
```

to

```
http://host_name.com/fr/booking?param=1&param=2
```

I tried it this way, but it doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\/booking(.*)
RewriteRule ^/booking(.*) /fr/booking$2 [L, R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should be able to do this to redirect the query string to a new one.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /+booking\?param=([^&\s]+)&param=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /fr/booking?param=%1&param=%2 [L, R=302]
```

Let me know how this works for you.